# scenarioContext.scenarioInfo.getScenarioName() is not working in Karate 0.9.6, what is the alternative?

Tags: bdd, karate, dsl

In karate.core version 0.9.5
`scenarioContext.scenarioInfo.getScenarioName()` , this was working
but in karate 0.9.6 ,
`scenarioContext.scenarioInfo.getScenarioName()` is not working.
what is the alternative to it in Karate 0.9.6

Answer (score -1):

Please focus on 1.0 now: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

It will be:

```
* def name = karate.scenario.name
```

You are welcome to contribute code to fix this in 0.9.6, this is open-source.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Regarding , "focus on 1.0"
It would be great , if you would add such points in the earlier version release notes.
It could save other's time and efforts.

Comment: @Engineer we can't go and update all old release notes when we create new versions, no project ever does this :)

Comment: No Worries, one day everything would be fine.